# Считывание текущей даты Android

Tags: java, android, дата

Имеется следующий код:

```
package asus.example.com.fitnessapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class IndicationsFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText pulse;
    Button save;
    TextView textView;

    public IndicationsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_indications, container, false);
        pulse = view.findViewById(R.id.pulse);
        save = view.findViewById(R.id.save);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        final Date date = new Date();
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String sPulse = pulse.getText().toString();
                textView.setText(date.getDay()+"."+date.getMonth()+"."+date.getYear()+" Pulse="+sPulse);
                //textView.setText(date.toString());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Задача - считать текущее число, месяц и год. Однако почему-то объект класса Date содержит не текущую дату, а 3.9.118. Однако если выводить дату через `data.toString()`, то выводит все как надо. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблемы нету.

> - A year y is represented by the integer y - 1900.
> - A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.
> - A date (day of month) is represented by an integer from 1 to 31 in the usual manner.
> - An hour is represented by an integer from 0 to 23. Thus, the hour from midnight to 1 a.m. is hour 0, and the hour from noon to 1 p.m. is
>     hour 12.

Источник: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date

Метод класса Date - toString() возвращает строку в формате 'day mon dd hh:mm:ss zz yyyy'